# Is there a tool to analyze PHP code to check whether returned value is used properly?

Tags: php, static-code-analysis, phpmd, phpcs

Let's say I have the following code:

```
$result = $thirdPartyAPI->doSomething(); // returns false if error
if ($result == false) {
    return $someErrorCode;
}

// process the valid $result
```

I have lots of calls to the `$thirdPartyAPI` spread throughout the code, so I don't want to forget about checking if `$result` is a valid one or an error happened.

I've checked [PHP Code Sniffer](https://github.com/squizlabs/PHP_CodeSniffer) and [PHP Mess Detector](http://phpmd.org/) tools, but I've found none of their rules to be appropiate for this particular case.

**I'm wondering if there is a tool (such a static code analysis one) that is able to report whether I forgot to check that a returned value has a certain value.**

Comment: The tool you're after is called `class`. You said you're having lots of those calls spread through the code. Why not simply wrap the use scenario in a class that will deal with success and errors for you? I don't see the need for static analysis here if you can solve it using the tools we have at our disposal..

Comment: PHPUnit for unit testing will help, as you can validate that the code return is checking/doing something on the return values.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts @Mjh. I understand you. A `class` wrapping the functionality would save me lots of similar code. But, I will still have the same problem: that class would return a valid value or `false` in case an error happened. And I should check for both. I would be in the same situation. It could throw an exception, but I'm not a big fan of throwing them when you can check for a specific value (it's not an _exceptional_ use case)

Comment: Unit testing is a very good idea @StevenScott, and I was thinking of them as a possibility. But, the `$thirdPartyAPI` access to a database, so those tests won't be very fast. Additionally, it won't tell me if I forget to check the returned value if I don't write a test for that code. I would have two things to remember. But I agree with you, it could be a nice possibility to check the correctness of my code. Thanks!

Comment: @rchavarria Actually, the database code you would mock to keep it quick. The PHPUnit testing can also output code coverage, so you can see if you tested a scenario or not, and it also contains a skeleton generator to build the outline of what needs to be tested.  Automated Testing is a definite requirement for the long haul, and quality code.

Answer (score 1):

Since 2017 there is: [PHPStan](https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan)

I use it and it works like a charm. [Here is simple intro to it](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/01/28/why-I-switched-scrutinizer-for-phpstan-and-you-should-too/)

Comment: Interesting. It seems it uses *type hints* to improve the static analysis. It would be useful to check that a method returns a value of the desired type. But that's not exactly what I'm looking for here. I'm looking for some tool that warns me if I forgot to check the return value, not if the method returns the right type of value. Anyway, it'd be awesome if you can share a link to some rules you think could help me.

Comment: Oh, I see now. You want a custom check, that ensures you have special code after "$thirdPartyAPI->...", right? If so, you can write a sniff for that. I can help you to set it up, just write an email: https://github.com/tomasvotruba